# SQL CASE Question

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I don't know if this can be done but I thought I'd ask.

What I want to do is have a case statement query and if a 1 begin another action. if 0 don't do anything.

For Example

```
select CASE WHEN client.deathofdeath = yes THEN 1 

        do another select in here (which is another table)

Else 0 End AS DeathDate

From Client client
```

Can this be done?

Comment: I'm unsure what you are trying to do here? Is the other select intended to return additional columns that only apply if client.deathofdeath = yes or a second result set?

Comment: Only if "do another select in here" returns a scalar value (SELECT COUNT(*) From AnotherTable)

Answer (score 3):

Not inside a CASE statement.

If you want to do control flow operations like this, use IF instead.  The @dateofDeath variable can either be a T-sql variable you declare and assign, or it can be a SELECT statement itself.

```
IF @dateofDeath = 'yes' BEGIN
   do something
END ELSE BEGIN
   do something else
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this: do something if something is true/exists in another table?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Client WHERE deathofdeath = yes)
   SELECT stuff FROM OtherTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Like unclepaul84 said you could do something like this:

```
select
    CASE
        WHEN client.deathofdeath = yes THEN (select top 1 therow from othertable where clientid=clientid.clientid)
        Else 0
    End AS DeathDate
From
    Client client
```